# jQuery - hide a span on document.ready

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a span on document.ready.  I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Set the stuff we want to be able to use in javascript, but not display in the browser window invisible
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            ('#_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_lType').hide()
        });
</script>
```

But, I get error "Object doesn't support this property or method" in IE7 debugger.  I verified in the source that the object exists as a `<span>` and the id is correct.

Comment: I think it chokes on the leading `_`. IIRC that is not a  valid starting character for an identifier

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli - LOL.  Love to, but its all my company supports.
@Pekka - doesnt appear to be the case (thank goodness cause this is ASP.NET generated naming).  Neal's solution hid it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_lType').hide();
    });
```

You left off the `$`.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a $ infront of the span selector.
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
 //Set the stuff we want to be able to use in javascript, but not display in the browser window invisible     
 $(document).ready(function () {             
   $('#_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_lType').hide();
 }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be the root of your problem, but note that `_` is an [invalid starting character for an ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/types.html#type-name).

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: If I'm not wrong, despite the fact that it is not recommended, IDs starting with `_` works anyway. (Or at least they did [I used to have a project months ago that used #_name]).

Comment: @Charlie they work, but only if the browsers are lenient. It probably won't be a real-life problem in most cases but I wouldn't do it if it can be help